# Function() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python

I am using python to call a method in one class that is in one file from a method in another class of other file

Suppose my file is `abc.py` that contains

```
class data : 

         def values_to_insert(a,b):
               ......
                ......
```

another file is `def.py`

```
import abc
class values:
      data=abc.data()
      def sendvalues():
          a=2
          b=3
          data.values(a,b)
```

When I run this file it gives an error:  `values() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: Probably because the `'self'` parameter for Python methods is a very basic issue.

Comment: ok. i thought the downvote was not justified considering the user is very new to this site.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If it's in a class, your method should be :

```
def values_to_insert(self, a, b):
```

You can read about the reasoning for this [here](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls).